# If an element $b$ of a $C^*$-algebra $B$ is self-adjoint with $\delta=\|b-b^2\|<\frac14$ then there is a projection $p\in B$ with $\|b-p\|\leq2\delta$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, self-adjoint-operators

If an element $b$ of a $C^*$-algebra $B$ is self-adjoint with $\delta=\|b-b^2\|<\frac14$, then there is a projection $p\in B$ with $\|b-p\|\leq2\delta$

I believe the proof as following however I am not sure, is this true or not? (The specific details of the proof may vary depending on the specific context and properties of the $C^*$-algebra B)

Given that $b$ is a self-adjoint element in a $C^*$-algebra $B$ with $\delta = \| b - b^2\|  < \frac14$, we want to show that there exists a projection $p \in B$ such that $\| b - p\|  \leq  2\delta$.

Since $b$ is self-adjoint, it can be written as $b = a + ic$, where $a$ and $c$ are self-adjoint elements and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Consider the polynomial function $f(z) = z^2$. Since $\delta = \| b - b^2\|$, we have:
$$\| b - b^2\|  = \| f(b) - b^2\|\,.$$

Using the triangle inequality and the fact that $\| x^2\|  = \| x\|^2$ for any self-adjoint element $x$ in a $C^*$-algebra, we can write:
$$\| f(b) - b^2\|  \leq  \| f(b) - b\|  + \| b - b^2\|  = \| b^2 - b\|  + \| b - b^2\| \,.$$

Now, let's focus on the term $\| b^2- b\|$. We can expand it as follows:
$$\| b^2- b\|  = \| (a + ic)^2 -(a + ic)\|  = \| (a^2 - c^2) + 2iac - (a + ic)\| \,.$$

Using the fact that $\| x + y\|  \leq  \| x\|  + \| y\|$  for any elements $x$ and $y$ in a $C^*$-algebra, we can write:
$$\| b^2 - b\|  \leq  \| a^2 - c^2 - a\|  + \| 2iac - ic\|  = \| a^2 - c^2 - a\|  + \| ic\| \| 2a - 1\| \,.$$

Since $a$ and $c$ are self-adjoint elements,$$ \| a^2 - c^2 - a\|  = \| a^2 - a - c^2\|  \leq  \| a^2 - a\|  + \| c^2\| \,.$$

Using the fact that $\| xy\|  \leq  \| x\| \| y\|$  for any elements $x$ and $y$ in a $C^*$-algebra, we have:
$$\| a^2 - a\|  \leq  \| a\| \| a - 1\| \,.$$

Combining these inequalities, we obtain:
$$\| b^2 - b\|  \leq  (\| a\| \| a - 1\|  + \| c^2\| ) + \| ic\| \| 2a - 1\| \,.$$

Since $\| a\| , \| c\|  \leq  \| b\|$, we can further simplify:
$$\| b^2 - b\|  \leq  (\| b\| \| a - 1\|  + \| b\|^2) + \| ic\| \| 2a - 1\| \,.$$

Now, we know that $\| b^2 - b\|  < \frac14$ (given $\delta < \frac14$). Therefore, we can write:
$$(\| b\| \| a - 1\|  + \| b\|^2) + \| ic\| \| 2a - 1\|  < \frac14\,.$$

Let's define $p = (b + b^*)/2$, where $b^*$ denotes the adjoint of $b$. Note that $p$ is self-adjoint since $b$ is self-adjoint. Now, we can calculate $\| b - p\|$:
$$\| b - p\|  = \| b - (b + b^*)/2\|  = \| (b - b^*)/2\|  = \| ic/2\|  = \| c/2\| \,.$$

Since $\| ic\|  = \| c\|$, we have $$\| b - p\|  = \| c/2\|  = \| ic/2\|  \leq  \| ic\|  = \| c\| \,.$$

Combining this with the inequality we obtained earlier, we have:
$$\| b - p\|  \leq  \| c\|  \leq  (\| b\| \| a - 1\|  + \| b\|^2) + \| ic\| \| 2a - 1\|  < \frac14\,.$$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: If an element b of a C*-algebra B is self-adjoint with δ=∥b−b²∥<1/4, then there is a projection p∈B with ∥b−p∥≤2δ. here is the question @Shaun can you please help me here.

Comment: I can't help you with this question. It's beyond my area. However, if you want someone to help you, then you are best formatting the question using MathJax. I have already commented with a link to a tutorial.

Comment: Let $\sigma(b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ denote the spectrum of $b.$ Denote $f(x)=x-x^2.$ Then $\sigma(b-b^2)=f(\sigma(b)).$ Therefore the problem can be reduced to the analysis of the function $f(x)$  on $\sigma(b),$ with the assumption $\max\{|f(x)|\,:\, x\in \sigma(b)\}=\delta<{1\over 4}.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma(b)$ denote the spectrum of $b.$ Then  $$\sigma(b-b^2)=\{x-x^2 \,:\, x\in \sigma(b)\}$$ We have
$$\delta:=\|b-b^2\|=\max\{|x-x^2|\,:\,x\in \sigma(b)\}$$ Therefore $|x-x^2|\le \delta$ for $x\in \sigma(b).$ The  inequality $|x-x^2|\le \delta$ is equivalent to
$$ x\in \textstyle\left [{1\over 2}-\sqrt{{1\over 4}+\delta}, {1\over 2}-\sqrt{{1\over 4}-\delta}\right ]\cup \left [{1\over 2}+\sqrt{{1\over 4}-\delta}, {1\over 2}-\sqrt{{1\over 4}+\delta}\right ]$$
Therefore $\sigma(b)$ is contained in the union of two disjoint intervals, say $I_1\cup I_2.$ For $x\in I_1$ we have $|x|\le 2\delta.$ For $x\in I_2$ there holds $|1-x|\le 2\delta.$  Let $f(x)={\bf 1}_{I_2}(x).$ Then $f$ is continuous  on $\sigma(b),$ as $I_1\cap I_2=\emptyset.$ By the continuous functional calculus the element $f(b)$ is a projection. Moreover
$$\|b-f(b)\|\le \max\left [\max\{|x|\,:\,x\in I_1\},\ \max\{|x-1|\,:\,x\in I_2\}\right ]$$
The last quantity is less than or equal $2\delta.$

Comment: thank you for help